# Two numbers $90$ and $m$ share exactly three positive divisors. What is the greatest of these three common divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Two numbers $90$ and $m$ share exactly three positive divisors. What is the greatest of these three common divisors.

The divisors of 90 are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, and 90.

I'm not sure what the number could be or even what m would be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Both numbers must have $1$ as a divisor, so we need to find two more. $90=2.3^2.5$. If we pick two different prime factors, then we add $3$ divisors. For example, pick $2$ and $3$. Then $2$, $3$ and $6$ are divisors. Hence we must pick $3$ and $9$ the two other divisors.

Comment: So 9 is the answer?

Comment: Yes, $1$, $3$ and $9$. Otherwise, we can find divisors more than $3$.

Comment: Does this mean m=27?

Comment: this mean is $m=27$.

Comment: We don't know what $m$ is.  We know that it has a factor of $9$ and does not have any factors of $2$ or $5$.  It could be $9$, it could be $81$, it could be $63$, it could be $3^7\cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot 83$.  The question just asked for the maximum common divisor, and that is $9$.

Comment: Ross Millikan comment is better than me.

Comment: You dont ask what is $m$.